# The line integral of the $E$-field from $A$ to $B$ is equal to $\phi_{B} - \phi _{A}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

In the chapter *Electric fields in matter*, Purcell says,

> The line integral of the field, reckoned over any internal path from $A$ to $B$, must be just  $\phi_{B} - \phi _{A}$.

The field above is an electric field produced by an electrostatic charge distribution. There must be a sign mistake here because
$$\phi_{B} - \phi _{A}=-\int_{X_0}^{B}\textbf{E}\cdot \textbf{dl}-\bigg [\color{red}{-}\int_{X_{0}}^{A}\textbf{E}\cdot \textbf{dl}\bigg ] =\int_{B}^{X_0}\textbf{E}\cdot \textbf{dl} +\int_{X_0}^{A}\textbf{E}\cdot \textbf{dl}=\int_{B}^{A}\textbf{E}\cdot \textbf{dl} ,$$

whereas the line integral from $A$ to $B$ is simply $\int_{A}^{B}\textbf{E}\cdot \textbf{dl}$. I checked the three editions of the book, all of them said exactly the same thing. Is his statement wrong in this case?

Comment: I corrected what appeared to be an important typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a missing minus sign. The electric field is $\mathbf{E} = -\nabla \phi$, So, for any path $\gamma$ starting from the point $A$ to the point $B$, the correct equation is
\begin{align}
\phi(B) - \phi(A) &= \int_{\gamma} \nabla \phi \cdot d\mathbf{l} \\
&= \int_{\gamma} - \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}
\end{align}

---

By the way, it is typically not a good idea to use the notation $\int_{A}^B$ for line integrals in $\Bbb{R}^3$, because it is very possible that the integral depends on the path chosen. Of course, in electrostatics, it doesn't matter, because the integral of an electrostatic field doesn't depend on the path taken. However, if you later on take line integrals of magnetic fields, or for example take integrals of non-conservative electric fields (in the context of electrodynamics) then the path of integration is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $\phi_B$ and $\phi_A$ refer to the values of electric potential at $A$ and $B$,

The difference in potential between two points is the negative of the integral of the electric field over that path.

Hence , it does seem the author has made a sign mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even generally speaking, if an electrostatic line of force is directed from $\vec{A}$ to $\vec{B}$, and the electrostatic potentials at the point are $V(\vec{A})$ and $V(\vec{B})$, the integral $$\int_{\vec{A}}^{\vec{B}}\vec{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{l} \geq 0$$ since the angle between $\vec{E}$ and $\mathrm{d}\vec{l}$ at each point is effectively zero along the line of force. Also the potential $V(\vec{A})$ should be greater than $V(\vec{B})$, since any positive charge would travel automatically along the line of force, thus, it seems it should be $$V(\vec{A})-V(\vec{B})=\int_{\vec{A}}^{\vec{B}}\vec{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{l}$$